# Web3 js React Native - Issue in creating account and calling contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

My requirement is to create an eth account and do transaction.

In Web 0.20.0 I am able to create web3.personal.newAccount and able to get create contract object. When I am using that created contract object to call methods I am getting HTTP synchronous not supported. I am using a test private network.

In Web 1.0.0 I am not able to create account but I can get a contract and call its methods.

Can you help me how I can achieve both.

My code snippet

```
 var data=web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
 alert("Response"+JSON.stringify(res));
```

or

```
  web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32),function(err,res){         
     if(err){
       alert("creating account error "+err);                   
     }else{
       alert("creating account success "+JSON.stringify(res));                   
     }
  })
```

Comment: Share your code. Chances are you simply need to add an error first callback function to your Web3 calls to make them asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per web1.0 API document use web3.eth.personal.newAccount() for create new account. API document is not updated for getAccounts, unlockAccount, lockAccount, sendTransaction, but it will work.

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount("Password", function(err, result){
   if(err){
       alert("Error"+ err);
       return;
   }
   alert("Account address: "+ result);
});
```